# Getting two letter language code from get_current_language

Tags: django, internationalization

I am using Django internationalization and use the `get_current_language` call to get the current language. However, that is a language code plus region code (e.g. `en-gb`), while I only want the language code (e.g. `en`).

How can I get just the two-letter language code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split on the dash.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

> If a base language is available but the sublanguage specified is not, Django uses the base language. For example, if a user specifies de-at (Austrian German) but Django only has de available, Django uses de.

Comment: How do I split on the dash in the template?

Comment: unless you make a filter, you can't. But why do you need to know the language in the template?

Comment: @BrianH. to select the current language in a language-selection dropdown list

Comment: Can you cook the data before-hand and then give it to the template?

Comment: @mccainz I need it in all templates

Comment: I ended up putting it in a context processor.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of expands on @mccainz's answer.

I propose you create a custom template filter, as [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
@register.filter
def country_only(value):
    return value[0:value.find("-")]
```

Usage would be:

```
{{lang|country_only}}
```